# return out of order rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, dense-rank

This is a relational table in Postgres.

I have a table that is constantly receiving records. The structure is this:

group | object_date | key | event_tmstmp

- where group is a unique identifier of a group of records
- key is a string that contains a datetime (ie: 'sometext/some/more/20190324121233.csv)
- where object date an int of the substring of key (the value above, so 20190324121233)
- where event_tmstp is a datetime that defaults to now() when the row is inserted

What I want to do:

- sort the rows by event_tmstmp
- for each group of rows, return any rows that are "out of order" according to the object_date

ex:

```
'group1' | 20190324121233 | 'sometext/some/more/20190324121233.csv' | 2019-09-26 14:57:12.747638
'group1' | 20190324121234 | 'sometext/some/more/20190324121234.csv' | 2019-09-26 14:58:12.747638
'group1' | 20190324121236 | 'sometext/some/more/20190324121236.csv' | 2019-09-26 15:00:12.747638
'group1' | 20190324121235 | 'sometext/some/more/20190324121235.csv' | 2019-09-26 15:01:12.747638
'group1' | 20190324121237 | 'sometext/some/more/20190324121237.csv' | 2019-09-26 15:02:12.747638
'group1' | 20190324121238 | 'sometext/some/more/20190324121238.csv' | 2019-09-26 15:05:12.747638
'group1' | 20190324121241 | 'sometext/some/more/20190324121241.csv' | 2019-09-26 15:06:12.747638
'group1' | 20190324121240 | 'sometext/some/more/20190324121240.csv' | 2019-09-26 15:08:12.747638
```

So what I would want returned are the rows:

```
'group1' | 20190324121235 | 'sometext/some/more/20190324121235.csv' | 2019-09-26 15:01:12.747638
'group1' | 20190324121240 | 'sometext/some/more/20190324121240.csv' | 2019-09-26 15:08:12.747638
```

here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table_1 AS a
WHERE a.object_date >
      ( SELECT b.object_date
        FROM table_1 AS b
        ORDER BY b.event_tmstmp DESC
        LIMIT 1
      );
```

but this only returns one row, not for each `group`.

I'm thinking I need a partition by clause to accomplish this. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(object_date) over (order by event_tmstmp) as prev_object_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev_object_date > object_date;
```

Comment: Thanks this seems like it would work in theory, but you can't do an operator between event_tmstmp (timestamp without a timezone) and object_date (bigint)